# is a higher voltage battery a more efficient energy deliverer than a lower voltage battery?

Tags: battery-chemistry

a DC electric motor moving a car. will it experience the same torque with current provided from a 4V battery with a capacity of 1000 Ah as with current provided from a 400V battery with a capacity of 100 Ah? according to math, P=V x A it should be the same, but would 4V be enough to move that car, even though it is supposedly moving so much more current (same C rates)? i have read about "energy efficiency" where higher voltage batteries are more efficient deliverers of energy as opposed to higher capacity ones, but don't understand why.

Answer (score 2):

Any given motor will develop torque proportional to current.  However, within some reasonable power range motors can be built with considerable latitude in their voltage versus current tradeoff.  For example, a 1 kW motor could be made for 100 V 10 A operation, or 200 V 5 A operation.  Once the motor has been chosen though, you're stuck with that tradeoff.

This tradeoff doesn't go infinitely in both directions due to practical limitations.  If you use too low of a voltage, then the current becomes so high that conductors need to be thick and expensive.  Note the losses is wires goes with the square of the current, or put another way, for the same power loss you need copper proportional to the square of the current with DC.  With AC skin effect gets in the way and makes things more complicated.

At the other end, high voltages become difficult to handle and keep safe.  Above a few 100 Volts, electronic components get a lot more expensive and you have significant safety issues.

Comment: so is it current (A=C/s) that moves the electric motor? what is the meaning of power here? P=V*I so a higher voltage would need less current for the same power output. BUT, if the battery provides a higher voltage (given the same resistors/wiring are used) it also provides higher currents so it seems to me it is the current that flows through the motor (which creates the magnetic field which actually turns the axle) that causes the car to move. the voltage provided by the battery only need to be high enough to ensure a high enough rate of current.

Comment: @guywi: For *any one motor*, higher voltage means higher current (all else being equal), which means higher torque.  My point was that motors can be made for the same power with some latitude in their voltage and current combinations.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. i have a lot to learn. in your example, how can 5A provide the same torque as 10A?

Comment: ok i guess if the radius of the motor is varied, 5A can deliver the same torque as 10A. I still don't understand what the voltage rating means from the point of view of the electric motor, since the only thing it seems to care about is electric current which establishes its torque. Isn't the voltage only important on the delivery side (for the battery, such that it can deliver the current needed for the motor)? In that case, the motor always wants the most current possible, but the delivery system (due to losses) always wants the smallest current possible. Am I right?

Comment: @guywi: Coils can be made that are about the same size, but with less turns of thicker wire or more turns of thinner wire.  The thicker wire will require more current but at a lower voltage than the thin wire, when both are creating the same size magnetic field.  This same concept can be applied to the windings in a motor to target it for high current and low voltage operation, or low current and high voltage, with both being able to deliver the same output power.  For the *same* motor, 5A will result in half the torque as 10A, but I'm talking about different motors with the same power.

Comment: i understand. thank you very much. another concept i can't grasp is the meaning of voltage for the electric motor. it seems all the motor needs to operate is a magnetic field which is generated by current. why does the electric motor "care" whether the current is fed to it from a 100V or a 200V battery? Isn't the concept of voltage useful only when talking about whatever delivers the current to the motor, like a battery?

Comment: V=IxR...thinner wires = less current but higher voltage to drive the current through the higher resistance of the thinner wire.....

Comment: i know engineers reading this probably think these questions are ridiculous but not to a chemist (like myself). my work actually deals with creating materials for new batteries. chemists, materials scientists, etc don't have the engineering background and we especially lack a basic understanding of how the batteries we (sometimes) create actually power devices in the real world so i appreciate you not referring me "to the www for more answers".

Comment: To me voltage is an actual driving force, directly related to the Gibbs Free Energy of a chemical reaction. This is why from my perspective it is ridiculous to talk about voltages for an instrument which uses energy (instead of delivering it) like a light bulb or an electric motor. To the engineer however, V can always be calculated based on the R and the I trough a resistor. So i guess from this perspective, a fridge can have a voltage rating, which to me is an indirect way of describing how much current it can carry through its wires and internal hardware without damage.

Comment: The fundamental (assumption ?) is that voltage , current and resistance are related. Change one of them and one of the others will change. In a specific motor the resistance of the wires stays the same (Not strictly true, it changes with temp, but not by much ). Increase Voltage, resistance is fixed then the current increases. Make the wires thinner (increase resistance), Voltage stays the same then lower current. The issue with motors is torque. Torque is related to magnetic field strength.  Magnetic field = Current and number of windings. Now it's a design trade off

Comment: The Voltage is a designed for criteria in both performance and safety aspects. If the voltage is know we have fixed one part of equations that allow us to workout the rest. Motors need a certain torque (magnetic field strength) which is related to the current and number of windings. Balancing the number of windings means how big they are Vs the resistance. we optomise for the most efficient use of Power. Voltage is also very important for determining the spacings between conductors. So to the Designer the Voltage rating has 2 roles, both critical. Get 1 wrong and things get interesting.

Comment: @Spoon thank you. this is exactly the type of discussion i was looking for. i understand it is desirable to minimize current due to heating losses through resistors. on the flip side, higher voltage is desirable to maximize power. given the wires stay the same so resistance is fixed how can voltage be increased w/out increasing the current as well?

Comment: @guywithaquestion . There are two answers. Simple No, you increase voltage you also increase current if your resistance stays the same. I believe physics controls this aspect. More complex Yes you can increase the voltage and have the current & resistance stay the same provided the voltage is pulsed such that the overall power stays the same. Indeed this is how some circuits achieve higher efficiency as they operate the switching components at their least resistance mode briefly. Power wasted in a resister is = voltage drop across resistor x current through resistor = heat. See Martin' Answer

Answer (score 0):

Transferring the same power at higher voltage means less current is flowing, P=V*I.

Given that the loss is due to (I^2)R due to resistance of the cables, internal resistance of the battery and resistances in the motor windings, you want to keep the current as low as possible, therefore you want to keep the voltage as high as possible.

Comment: thank you. i am confused about this, even though i am familiar with the concept. if we keep the resistors fixed, based on I=V/R, a higher voltage will draw a higher intensity of current. so then how then can a higher voltage command less current in P=V*I?

Comment: @guy: do the sums with `P`=100 `V`=2 and `P`=100 `V`=20. What `I` do you get from `P=V*I` in the two cases? Note that this requires two distinct motor designs of the same wattage.

Comment: yes i get that. based on P=V*I, 20V will only need 5A, whereas 2V will need 50A to achieve the same 100W of power. my question is, given the same wiring/resistance, what will stop the imaginary battery operating at 20V from delivering 10x current, so 500A instead of 5A?

Comment: The 20V battery will only deliver the current into the load as given by I = V/R.

Comment: @Martin what does that mean? V=20V, R is the same as it was for the 2V battery. Doesn't the 20V battery give substantially higher current?

Comment: No, R is not the same as it was for the 2V battery. R = V/I, so in the case of the 20V,5A load, R=20/5 = 4 ohms. In the case of the 2V battery, R = 2/50 = 0.04 ohms. These are from your figures of 20V*5A = 100W and 2V*50A = 100W. You need to decide what is fixed and what is variable, are you talking about a fixed resistance or whatever resistance it takes to dissipate a fixed power, these are not the same.

Comment: from my post above : "my question is, given the same wiring/resistance, what will stop the imaginary battery operating at 20V from delivering 10x current, so 500A instead of 5A?" -- so R is fixed in I=V/R. V changes from 20 to 5. Based on this a higher V will draw a higher current. However, based on the other relationship, P=V*I, a higher voltage draws a smaller current. i don't understand how both of these relationships can be true.